# How to import wordpress posts with images and featured images?

Tags: wordpress

I have used Tools->import&export but it didn't work. I have tried using Wp-All-Import and Export plugin then also it is not working. Only the content imported not the images. How to fix this issue. Is there any way to import posts with images?

Comment: You can use this plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-media-with-selected-content/). At least it worked for my case.

Answer (score 17):

The import and export of posts, pages, comments, and media is currently part of WordPress core. So use the default import and export utility to get this done. In this example I export posts but the same goes for pages, etc.

1. Log into the WordPress website you need to copy from.
2. On the dashboard go to Tools > Export > WordPress > Posts
   (install the plugin if needed)
3. Save the file
4. Repeat the process but this time choose Media (rename the file so you don't overwrite the prior one)
5. Log into the WordPress Site to copy to.
6. On the dashboard go to Tools > Import > WordPress
7. Select the posts file
8. Repeat step 6 and upload the media file.

All posts and media files are currently imported.

#### NOTES:

Although all media is now on the new server, I had to take care of one additional step and rename the domain name for all database entries pointing to the images. I used the below tool to do this. (backup your DB before you proceed just in case...)

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Instructions are on their website on how to update DB entries, in my case it had to run the tool and rename www.olddomain.com to www.newdomain.com.

Worked like a charm and Within 10 minutes I had all old data on the new server.

Comment: Pretty good answer, although for me it did not transfer over all images successfully (although some did work)

Comment: which table did you edit?

Comment: I took a similar approach, creating separate exports, but instead of then importing separate XML files, I first opened up each XML file and took all "<item>...</item>" tags from one file and added them to the bottom of the other file, effectively merging the two XML files into one.  I then imported the one merged XML file.  It took forever to process the import but it seems to have worked.  With this approach I didn't experience the issue Jordan Carter mentioned (although I may have been lucky).

Comment: The answers to a similar question on wordpress stackexchange were helpful for me as well: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257180/how-to-import-wordpress-posts-with-images-from-one-wordpress-site-to-another

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins available for the same. You can try the following:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-attachment-export/

Comment: This plugin has been obsolete since WordPress 4.4. Mentions it on the top of the plugin page.

Comment: You may try this tutorial that I created after successfully deploying the solution explained there in one of my project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_xK-HRpHMc